# Cannot bulk load because the filecould not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Acceso denegado.).'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando hacer una carga masiva de registros desde excel hacia sql, tengo un store procedure para poder realizarlo con la cadena para que pueda acceder a dicho archivo,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tarfia_masiva_in (@servicio varchar(15)) 
AS 
BEGIN 
  BULK INSERT tarifa_in FROM 'C:\Users\MiPc\OneDrive\Escritorio\ProyectoMAD\ProyectoMAD\Hojas' WITH( FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' ) 
END
```

sin embargo me aparece ese error al momento de hacerlo, estuve buscando y segun es un tema de permisos pero no tengo idea de donde dar el permiso para que pueda realizarse dicha operacion, alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Hacia qué motor de BD? Podrías incluir el procedimiento almacenado en tu pregunta? Igual, tampoco sabemos en qué sistema operativo está ubicado el archivo

Comment: `Acceso denegado` o el motor no tiene permisos para acceder al archivo, o este lo tienes abierto al mismo tiempo que intentas cargarlo.

Comment: estoy usando sql server, el procedure seria este CREATE PROCEDURE tarfia_masiva_in (@servicio varchar(15))
AS
BEGIN
BULK INSERT tarifa_in
FROM 'C:\Users\MiPc\OneDrive\Escritorio\ProyectoMAD\ProyectoMAD\Hojas'
WITH(
 FIRSTROW = 2,
 FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
 ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
 )
END

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante 
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). 
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Si el servidor está corriendo físicamente en otro equipo, `C:\Users\MiPc\...` no es una carpeta válida por que es local, si el archivo y el servidor corren en el mismo equipo, verifica que el servidor tenga acceso full a la carpeta mencionada y que el archivo no este abierto al mismo tiempo que lo vayas a importar.